# Is there an analogue to Java IllegalStateException in Python?

Tags: python, exception

IllegalStateException is often used in Java when a method is invoked on an object in inappropriate state. What would you use instead in Python?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

In Python, that would be `ValueError`, or a subclass of it.

For example, trying to `.read()` a closed file raises "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file".

Comment: The answer from roskakori is better. ValueError is "Raised when an operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError". This sounds identical to IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 24):

`ValueError` seems more like the equivalent to Java's `IllegalArgumentException`.

[RuntimeError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RuntimeError) sounds like a better fit to me:

> Raised when an error is detected that doesn’t fall in any of the other categories. The associated value is a string indicating what precisely went wrong.

Most of the time you don't want to do any special error handling on such an error anyway, so the generic `RuntimeError` should suffice out of the box.

In case you do want to handle it differently to other errors just derive your own exception from it:

```py
class IllegalStateError(RuntimeError):
    pass
```

Comment: +1 to this one. ValueError is "Raised when an operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as IndexError". This sounds identical to IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 13):

[ValueError](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html?highlight=valueerror#exceptions.ValueError) sounds appropriate to me:

> Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that has the right type but an inappropriate value, and the situation is not described by a more precise exception such as [IndexError](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html?highlight=valueerror#exceptions.IndexError).

Comment: "inappropriate value" is vague enough that I think it applies for passing arguments to a function which would be ok in some conditions, but invalid due to the object's current state.

Comment: What if the function has no arguments?

Comment: In Python, `self` *is* an argument!